# Why is the asymptotic density of the square-free numbers the same as the Probability of coprimality?

Tags: number-theory

There are several proofs for both statements in the sense that $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{ \#Copr(N)}{N^2}= \frac{1}{\zeta (2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\#Sqfr(N)}{N}$$ where $\#Sqfr(N)$ is the amount of square-free numbers smaller than $N$ and $\#Copr$ is the amount of coprime pairs $n,k \leq N$.

I was just wondering why would we expect this result, because the proofs [1](https://gjom.org/index.php/gjom/article/download/222/214/),[2](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Probability/TwoCoprime.shtml) I have seen so far don't really draw a connection between the two?

Comment: Why $N^2$ and not $N$ in the denominator?

Comment: @Zima Copr(N) is a count of the set of pairs of natural numbers below N that satisfy a certain property. Sqfr(N) is a count of the set of numbers below N which satisfy a given property. This accounts for the different exponents.

Comment: The same question was raised in the early days of MathOverflow. See whether any of the replies at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34971/coprimality-and-squarefree-numbers satisfies you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already answers to the same question on MathOverflow that @Gerry Myerson provided, but here's a brief explanation.

By Euler's product formula, both densities are equal to the product

$$\prod_{p}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^2}\right)}$$

where $p$ denotes the primes.

In terms of coprimality, $\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^2}\right)$ represents the probability that two numbers both aren't divisible by $p$. Since coprimality is multiplicative, then the product of the term over all primes should equal the probability that two random numbers are coprime.

In the context of squarefree integers, $\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^2}\right)$ represents the probability that a number isn't divisible by $p^2$. Since divisibility is also multiplicative, multiplying the term over all primes will result in the density of numbers not divisible by any squares - precisely the definition of squarefree integers. Another interpretation this product is a sieve that removes all prime squares.